# What's wrong with the following python code?

Tags: python

I have a following code which is supposed to implement Lagrange interpolation. Running this code gives an indentation error, which I have not been able to figure out where it comes from. Could anyone help me explain the source of this error, and potential ways to fix it?

```
points =[(0,0),(25,30),(50,10), (57,0)]
P = lagrange(points, 10)
print (P)

def lagrange(f, x):
        total = 0
        n = len(f)
        for i in xrange(n):
            xi, yi = f[i]

            def g(i, n):

                g_tot = 1
                for j in xrange(n):
                    if i == j:
                        continue
                    xj, yj = f[j]
                    g_tot *= (x - xj) / float(xi - xj)

                return g_tot 

            total += yi * g(i, n)
        return total
```

Comment: `indentation error` means indentation error. which IDE are you using? If you are using `pycharm`, type `commad+option+L(mac)` to reformat your code to avoid indentation errors! Also , Remember to define `lagrange ` before calling it!

Comment: Check if your code is indented with a mix of tabs and spaces. If it is, change to use one or the other

Answer (score 0):

The "unexpected indent" issue occurs when you type the above code into the python editor directly.  It's fine when running straight out of file.  (e.g. `python lagrange.py`)

To fix the indent issues, simply remove the blank lines in your program.  Or make sure each blank line has the expected number of spaces to continue or close the current block of code.

Comment: A nice compromise between removing white lines and balancing their indentation level is to comment them.

Answer (score -2):

Python uses whitespace to identify code-blocks.

points =[(0,0),(25,30),(50,10), (57,0)]
P = lagrange(points, 10)
print (P)

```
def lagrange(f, x):
    total = 0
    n = len(f)
    for i in xrange(n):
        xi, yi = f[i]

        def g(i, n):
            g_tot = 1
            for j in xrange(n):
                if i == j:
                    continue
                xj, yj = f[j]
                g_tot *= (x - xj) / float(xi - xj)
            return g_tot 

        total += yi * g(i, n)
    return total
```

`

Comment: Speaking of code blocks, please format your answer accordingly.